# Forwarding requests to external endpoint from an CFX service

Tags: web-services, cxf, single-page-application

Currently I am fighting with the following problem:

I need to forward SOAP requests to an external service in special cases (decision based on `tenantId` provided in the SOAP message). I created an interceptor for this task to extract `tenantId` from the message request, get assignment (each `tenantId` is assigned to its own service instance running on a different server) and if no assignment is made, I need to process the request just as normal.

Currently I implemented on this way: I create `HttpUrlConnection` in the interceptor and forward the request to an external endpoint (in case there is an assignment) and take the `outputStream` of the response and send the response over `HttpServletResponse.getOutputStream` etc...

I also need to consider that the interceptor be used with various service (`tenantId` must be provided in the SOAP request).

I also read about Provider and Dispatch objects not sure how this should work.

Is there any way to get target service and port (QNames) from the incoming message?

I cannot use Camel at the moment (only CXF is allowed).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try something like this :

```
/** Your interceptor */
public void handleMessage(SoapMessage msg) throws Fault {

    Exchange exchange = msg.getExchange();
    Endpoint ep = exchange.get(Endpoint.class);

    // Get the service name
    ServiceInfo si = ep.getEndpointInfo().getService();
    String serviceName = si.getName().getLocalPart();

    XMLStreamReader xr = msg.getContent(XMLStreamReader.class);
    if (xr != null) { // If we are not even able to parse the message in the SAAJInInterceptor (CXF internal interceptor) this can be null

        // You have the QName
        QName name = xr.getName();

        SOAPMessage msgSOAP = msg.getContent(SOAPMessage.class);

        // Read soap msg
        if (msgSOAP != null) {
            ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

            msgSOAP.writeTo(byteArrayOutputStream);
            String encoding = (String) msg.get(Message.ENCODING);
            String xmlRequest = new String(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray(), encoding);
        }

        // Forward to external service with JAX-RS implementation
        Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient()
                .target("http://your-target")
                .path("/custom-path")
                .request()
                .post(Entity.entity(xmlRequest, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML));
    }
}
```

Hope this help.